# Viewport Apply Conditional Toolbar with Sencha Touch

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, viewport, sencha-touch

Im going to MVC route with Sencha. I have a Viewport panel initialized much like the twitter example:

```
/**
* @author Jeff Blake
*/
Ext.regApplication('App', {
defaultTarget: 'viewport',
defaultUrl   : 'Viewport/index',
name         : 'App',
icon         : "mobile/public/resources/images/icon.png",
phoneStartupScreen : "mobile/public/resources/images/phone_startup.png",
//useHistory   : false,
//useLoadMask : true,

launch: function() {
    Ext.Viewport.init();
    Ext.Viewport.onOrientationChange();

    this.viewport = new App.Viewport({
        application: this
    });

    Ext.dispatch({
        controller: 'User',
        action    : 'index'
    });
}
});

/**
* @class App.Viewport
* @extends Ext.Panel
* This is a default generated class which would usually be used to initialize your     application's
* main viewport. By default this is simply a welcome screen that tells you that the app was 
* generated correctly.
*/
App.Viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
id        : 'viewport',
layout    : 'card',
fullscreen: true,
cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',

initComponent: function() {

    Ext.apply(this, {

        dockedItems: [
            {
                // Top Bar
                dock   : 'top',
                xtype  : 'toolbar',
                title  : 'Whats Good',
                items: [
                    {
                        text: 'About'
                    },

                ]
            }


        ]
    });


App.Viewport.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
}

});
Ext.reg('App.Viewport', App.Viewport);
```

New Code:

```
if (!App.viewport.getDockedComponent(homeBar)) {
        var homeBar = new App.HomeBar();
        App.viewport.addDocked(homeBar);
    }
```

I want to be able to conditionally apply DockedItems (toolbars) based on which Type of panel is currently rendered in the Viewport. EG: one for Login, Home screen, detail screen, etc.

I've tried using Ext.apply(App.Viewport, { dockedItems: [App.LoginBar]}); 
But that doesn't work. Currently it works to add the toolbar to the currently rendered Panel and setting it to fullscreen, but unfortunately transitions and things behave weirdly as the structure is

```
Panel
Toolbar
    Panel
    Toolbar
    /end Panel
/end Panel
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the reference to your application's viewport, you can come in through the 'App' namespace, which is automatically created by the name property of the regApplication config.

So you could make your toolbar button do this for example:

```
{
    text: 'About',
    handler: function() {
        App.viewport.getDockedItems()[0].setTitle('Pressed!');
    }
},
```

Which would make the title change when you press the button.

But now I better understand what it is you are trying to do, I recommend you don't dock a single, dynamically-changed toolbar to the outer viewport, but add individual toolbars to each of the (card) panels in it. That way they get to slide nicely too ;-)

Comment: Thats exactly it. Thanks James. And yes, that's what I am currently doing but the slide animation is not working properly so I was hoping this approach would solve that - as it makes more sense to dock Toolbars that work across multiple cards to the viewport.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a concern. The toolbars on panels should slide just as well!

Answer (score 2):

To programmatically add a docked item, I would recommend using

```
viewport.addDocked(loginBar);
```

Methods like this are far better than trying to update the original configuration of the component.

Then there is also a .removeDocked() method to take it off again.

Also make sure you are dealing with instances of the components, not trying to update their class.

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: Object #<an HTMLDivElement> has no method 'addDocked'

Comment: Ext.regApplication('App', {
 defaultTarget: 'viewport',
 defaultUrl   : 'Viewport/index',
 name         : 'App',
 icon   : "mobile/public/resources/images/icon.png",
 phoneStartupScreen : "mobile/public/resources/images/phone_startup.png",
 //useHistory   : false,
 //useLoadMask : true,

 launch: function() {
  Ext.Viewport.init();
  Ext.Viewport.onOrientationChange();
  
  this.viewport = new App.Viewport({
   application: this
  });

  Ext.dispatch({
   controller: 'User',
   action    : 'index'
  });
 }
});

Comment: Its something to do with making an instance of the component: I've tried things but can't get the App to create an instance of App.Viewport, assign it as the viewport, and then access the instance programmatically.

Comment: Yes, App.Viewport is a component 'class' and you need to instantiate it to actually place the component on the screen (as you have). But use the addDocked() method on that instance: this.viewport.addDocked(loginBar) ... where loginBar is also an instance (of the App.LoginBar component)

Comment: If you update the OQ to post all your JavaScript I reckon it would be easy to fix it up ;-)

Comment: Thanks James. I updated the question. I understand exactly what you're saying, but I'm having trouble creating an instance of viewport and then setting that as the viewport so I can the addDocked method on it.